# check if general exception is caught

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any rule in Sonarqube 6.7 (sonar-csharp-plugin-7.0) that helps us to check whether a general exception like System.Exception is caught in C# code? Similar rule was available in earlier versions of Sonarqube and not finding equivalent one in newer versions. As this is pretty much kind of basic check expecting it as part of core rule engine, and wondering whether I am missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for ["Exception" should not be caught when not required by called methods](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2221), which has been implemented for C#.

Comment: Is this the same? Looking for a rule that can identify all instances where  general exception such as System.Exception or System.SystemException is caught in a catch statement.  But functionality of "Exception" should not be caught when not required by called methods seems to be different.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Ann. I was testing it with wrong samples and got it corrected now.